# Trying to recreate the SlimNet model in TensorFlow and Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am currently working on recreating a SlimNet model based on this paper: "Slim-CNN: A Light-Weight CNN for Face Attribute Prediction (Ankit Sharma et. al. 2019)."

My code: https://github.com/Wierzbek/SlimNet-Tensorflow/blob/main/SlimNet.ipynb

I get the error "ValueError: A merge layer should be called on a list of inputs."

I assume the ConvBNReLU returns NULL but I have no clue why and I'm stuck with this error for 2 days. Any chance someone could help me?

SlimNet diagrams:

[image: img]
[image: img]
[image: img]

Regrds,
Kamil

Comment: I think in your code instead of `SlimModule(16, 64, 48, maaxpool1)()` you should write `SlimModule(16, 64, 48)(maaxpool1)`, same for other layers, previous layer is passed not as argument but inside second `()` parentheses.

Comment: So should I change the class to "Sequential" rather than "Model" ? I dont know how to pass that layer to SlimModules function

Comment: Any layer in Keras and any model in general works next way - `LayerName(param1, param2, ...)(previous_layer)`. So first pair of `()` is meant to pass params to layer-creating factory. And second `()` is meant to accept just previous layer of network. And in your case you don't pass anything to second `()` that is the reason of error, you have to pass previous layer.

Comment: Also have you tried passing a list? I.e. do `SlimModule(16, 64, 48, [maaxpool1])()`, i.e. instead of `maxpool1` pass `[maxpool1]`.

Comment: Also second `()` inside `SlimModule(16, 64, 48, [maaxpool1])()` maybe not needed, try doing `SlimModule(16, 64, 48, [maaxpool1])`.

Comment: when I pass a list I get this: TypeError: __init__() takes 4 positional arguments but 5 were given

Maybe I will try to create a call function inside the SlimModule, because the second bracket wit maaxpool1 doesnt work somehow, I need to input it to 2 other layers and them merge them

Comment: I found one of possible errors - Instead of `Concatenate([self.pointwise2.output(), self.depthwise.output()])` you should have `Concatenate()([self.pointwise2.output(), self.depthwise.output()])`, i.e. add `()` after Concatenate word. Then you have to fix padding there, to make two concatenated layer of equal shape.

Comment: Oh yes! I think I'm close!
Now the error says:
ValueError: A `Concatenate` layer requires inputs with matching shapes except for the concat axis. Got inputs shapes: [(None, 42, 52, 64), (None, 40, 50, 64)]
Are they not the same shape? How can I change the shape now? Thank you so much!

Comment: You can do either slicing to remove some border elements of bigger shape or you can do padding to add extra border zeros to smaller shape. For example if you have tensor `t` of shape `(None, 40, 50, 64)` you can pad it with zeros next way `t2 = tf.keras.layers.ZeroPadding2D(padding = 1)(t)`, then your `t2` will become of shape `(None, 42, 52, 64)` - exactly what you need!

Comment: I am trying to do that all day... 
Now I get the last number changed. The last one represents a number of filters is that right?
Operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (86, 106, 96) (86, 106, 128)

Comment: I couldnt edit previous post so I am writing another one, sorry if its against the rules. I could not find the issue, the shape looks better but still the last variable is different (its number of filters I think). I fixed the code completely because I had some other errors too. 
Here is the final code:
https://github.com/Wierzbek/SlimNet-Tensorflow/blob/main/SlimNet.ipynb
To solve the problem with the filters, I added a Dense layer with exact number of nodes as the other list. I really hope that doesnt affect the final outcome. I will try to train the model tomorrow. Thank you a lot Arty!

Comment: You can edit your post by clicking this link [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66279689/edit), also this word-link is located right at the bottom of your question-post.